# jQuery dialog: external file load not working from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please tell me what is up with this code? I can't for the life of me see whats stopping it from working. If I set it to `autoOpen: true` it works, but getting it to open from the button does not seem to work! Many thanks in advance.

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pextension").load('tour_extension_lb.aspx').dialog({ 
        bgiframe: true, 
        autoOpen: false, 
        position: 'center', 
        width: 440, 
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
    }); 

    $('a.extension-link').click(function () { $('#pextension').dialog('open'); return false; });     
});
```

**html:**

```
<a href="#" class="extension-link">OPEN EXTENSION DIALOG</a>

<div id="pextension" class="dialogBox" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try by changing your code

```
 function opendialog(){
    $("#pextension").dialog({ 
        bgiframe: true, 
        autoOpen: false, 
        position: 'center', 
        width: 440, 
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        open: loaddialogcontent();
    }); 
   }
 function loaddialogcontent(){
   $("#pextension").load('you file to load');
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.extension-link').click(opendialog);     
   opendialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pextension").dialog({ 
        bgiframe: true, 
        autoOpen: false, 
        position: 'center', 
        width: 440, 
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
           $(this).load('tour_extension_lb.aspx');
        }
    }); 

    $('a.extension-link').click(function (e) { 
       e.preventDefault();  
       $('#pextension').dialog('open'); 
    });     
});
```